# VBA to Choose Row Based on Two Criteria; One "Value" and the Other "InStr", maybe?

Tags: excel, vba

Currently using the following VBA in Excel to choose rows from master sheet (Sheet1) into another sheet (Sheet2)...

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim i, LastRow

LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
'this line finds the last row used in a sheet.

Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:M1000").ClearContents 
'this line clears the contents of Sheet2 from A2 to M1000.

For i = 2 To LastRow

If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "D").**Value = "OlsonJo"** And Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "H").**Value = "UT-STRL Administration"** Then  
'the two criteria are in this line; "OlsonJo" and "UT-STRL Administration"

Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "D").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

End If

Next i

End Sub
```

This successfully finds rows with both "OlsonJo" AND "UT-STRL Administration" in rows of the master sheet then copies and pastes these rows into Sheet2.

I would now like to expand the search capabilities on the master sheet. Still want to continue to using *Value = "OlsonJo"* but rather than using *Value = "UT-STRL Administration"* how can I use InStr to search rows for just the *UT-* part of "UT-STRL Administration"* so that I can include other tasks that begin with *UT-* in the Sheet2 results (i.e. "UT-Dept Commitee/Faculty Meeting" and "UT-Teaching-Medical School")?

Thank you in advance for your time! -Rick

Comment: `And Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "H").Value Like "UT*"`

Comment: Thank you, Scott.  You are a champion.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
Left(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "H").Value2, 3) = "UT-"
```

instead of

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "H").Value = "UT-STRL Administration"
```